# Incorrect Nested Module Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, module, path

I'll preface this with the fact that I'm new to RoR.  I have a class that resides in a nested module, `::Physical::Users::User`.  The code is organized into paths such as app\controllers\physical\users.

My problem comes when I try to use `form_for` like this:

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I get the error `ActionView::TemplateError undefined method 'physical_users_users_path'`

I understand that this has to do with rails expecting routes that don't match mine. In order to make my app work so that the resource :users goes directly to the correct directory (so that I don't have to use http:\myurl.com\physical\users\users\1', I put the following in my routes.rb file:

```
map.resources :users, :controller => 'physical/users/users'
```

When I run ">rake routes" I get the following:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)                   {:controller=>"physical/users/users", :action=>"index"}
          POST   /users(.:format)                   {:controller=>"physical/users/users", :action=>"create"}
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)               {:controller=>"physical/users/users", :action=>"new"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)          {:controller=>"physical/users/users", :action=>"edit"}
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)               {:controller=>"physical/users/users", :action=>"show"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)               {:controller=>"physical/users/users", :action=>"update"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)               {:controller=>"physical/users/users", :action=>"destroy"}
                 /:controller/:action/:id           
                 /:controller/:action/:id(.:format)
```

Is there a way to maintain the shorter url to my user resource and get `form_for` to look for the correct route?

Again, I'm new, so if there's anything I'm missing in this explanation, let me know!

--

In response to replies below, the controller resides at app/controllers/physical/users/users_controller.rb.

Changing the routing to use namespaces like:

```
map.namespace :physical do |physical|
  physical.namespace :users do |users|
    users.resources :users
  end
end
```

generates routes that are consistent with what `form_for` is looking for, but then I lose the ability to use the URL http:\mysite.com\users\1.

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning of your controller being named :controller=>"physical/users/users" ? -- normally it would just be "users"

Comment: Also -- what's the full path to your users_controller file? is it /app/controllers/physical/users_controller.rb ? or is it /app/controllers/physical/users/users_controller.rb ?

Comment: I'm following [Enterprise Rails](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596515201) by Dan Chak.  The physical layer indicates classes that interact with physical database models, while those in the logical layer deal with classes built on top of business logic, etc.

Comment: The controller resides at app/controllers/physical/users/users_controller.rb.

Comment: What is the user model called? Is it also `Physical::Users::User`?

Comment: mckeed - yes, the model is Physical::Users::User

Comment: @BryanMarble That's a rather bad naming scheme. The name of a class shouldn't indicate whether it's tied to the DB or not: that's letting too much implementation leak into your interface. That said, it should be possible to do what you're asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I've found to work is actually a combination of Jesse Wolgamott and sespindola's answers.  I've voted them both up.  I placed the following in my routes.rb file:

```
map.namespace :physical do |physical|
  physical.namespace :users do |users|
    users.resources :users
  end
end

map.resources :users, :controller => "physical/users/users"
```

If this seems kludgy and not really the best way to do it, leave a comment.  Thanks all for the help!

Comment: You should not need both the users.resource :users AND the map.resources :users -- only one should be present in your routes files. I recommend you steer away from a complicated scheme and just keep it simple. If you have a controller resources (as a first class citizen in your system), just have a map.resources :users.

Answer (score 1):

In routes, you must represent modules with namespaces:

```
namespace :physical do
  namespace :users do
    map.resources :users
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this and script/server complained.  Did you mean:

    map.namespace :physical do |physical|
      physical.namespace :users do |users|
        users.resources :users
      end
    end

This works in the sense that it creates the correct paths, but how would I then go about making sure that the path /users/:id goes to physical/users/users_controller?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @sespindola, but with the controller at app\controllers\physical\users --- I think it's a namespace issue

I think this may work for you:

```
map.resources :users, :path_prefix => ':physical'
```

Comment: If that's the case your answer is right.
I Thought he had the controller on app/controllers/physical/users/users.

Comment: Right! I'll ask him to confirm